# Hibernate/JPA query blocks forever

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

My application is experiencing a strange issue where sometimes it blocks forever when attempting to run an SQL query against the database, even if that is a small select statement on one single row.
This may occur at different points in the application, whenever it tries do execute a query (SELECT, UPDATE, etc.), which indicates this is perhaps a configuration issue.
With a tcpdump I was able to tell the query is never actually sent to the Oracle database, despite hibernate show_sql saying otherwise.
The worst thing is that as soon as the application blocks on a query for the first time, any other database queries in that machine (on different Threads) block in the same way, even though the machine is not nearly at its load capacity and can do any non-database work.
The only solution to this has been restarting the application, which runs as expected (with SQL queries) until at some random point in time (even days after) it blocks forever again...

This runs on
Hibernate 5.2.9.Final
Apache camel 2.19.2

applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- JPA Setup -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
            <list>
                <bean class="test.package.ReportingDbConnSetup" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


<bean id="transactionTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="ALWAYS" />

    <!-- username, password and connection url hidden -->

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="" />

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />

    <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="12" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="35" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="120" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="3" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="210" />

</properties>
```

Here is an example code block that might hang forever with no additional information:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public void saveOrUpdate(Object o){

        EntityManager em = null;
        try{
            em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(o);
            txn.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if (txn !=null && txn.isActive()) {
                txn.rollback();
            }
            LOG.error(e);
        }
        finally{
            if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
                try{
                    em.close();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    LOG.error(e);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but your code shouldn't compile, you're returning true in a method declared to return void. :?

Comment: sorry.. I changed to make the question simpler... updated now...

Comment: I saw this when my application was running out of connections. Check the number of connections when the application hangs. Just a hunch though. I had a connection pool leak which means once it reached its limits the application just hanged and this was very intermittent and a PITA to trace.

Comment: What is the easiest way to check the number of live connections in this case?